# How can activate a glass effect (windows Vista/7) in a console application using Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-7, console-application, windows-vista, aero-glass

As I can activate the glass effect on my console applications. I am using Windows 7 and Delphi 2010.

I found [this](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/05/glass-cmd-enables-aero-transparency-for-the-command-prompt/) application so it should be possible.

Comment: The console window is a shared resource. It does not belong to your program. Do not make global changes to a window that doesn't belong to you. If your customers want their console windows to look fancy, they can install the program you linked to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple of weeks ago I published [this article](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/glass-effect-in-a-delphi-console-application/) on my blog.

The key is use the [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969508%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions.

The `GetConsoleWindow` function retrieves the window handle used by the console associated with the calling process.

The `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` function enables the blur effect (glass) on the provided window handle.

```
program ConsoleGlassDelphi;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

    uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

type
  DWM_BLURBEHIND = record
    dwFlags                 : DWORD;
    fEnable                 : BOOL;
    hRgnBlur                : HRGN;
    fTransitionOnMaximized  : BOOL;
  end;

function DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd : HWND; const pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND) : HRESULT; stdcall; external  'dwmapi.dll' name 'DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow';//function to enable the glass effect
function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetConsoleWindow'; //get the handle of the console window

function DWM_EnableBlurBehind(hwnd : HWND; AEnable: Boolean; hRgnBlur : HRGN = 0; ATransitionOnMaximized: Boolean = False; AFlags: Cardinal = 1): HRESULT;
var
  pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND;
begin
  pBlurBehind.dwFlags:=AFlags;
  pBlurBehind.fEnable:=AEnable;
  pBlurBehind.hRgnBlur:=hRgnBlur;
  pBlurBehind.fTransitionOnMaximized:=ATransitionOnMaximized;
  Result:=DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, pBlurBehind);
end;

begin
  try
    DWM_EnableBlurBehind(GetConsoleWindow(), True);
    Writeln('See my glass effect');
    Writeln('Go Delphi Go');
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

This is just a basic example; you must check the Windows OS version to avoid issues.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This dose not work well if the "window Color and Appearance" is set to frost... white text on a white background